# gcc cant find definitions of stdio.h funcs and identities when gcc is executed by GNU Make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make, c-standard-library

I'm learning how GNU Make and makefile works.
I have a small project with 7 *.c and *.h files and a main.c file.

---

here's the makefile:

```
CC = "gcc"
CFLAGS = "-std=c11"

#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
# the PATH variable is set after I got the error. But adding this didnt change the result

src := src/lib
bin := bin

project:        $(bin)/aaa.o $(bin)/bbb.o $(bin)/ccc.o $(bin)/ddd.o $(bin)/eee.o $(bin)/fff.o $(bin)/main.o
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(bin)/aaa.o $(bin)/bbb.o $(bin)/ccc.o $(bin)/ddd.o $(bin)/eee.o $(bin)/fff.o $(bin)/main.o -o $(bin)/project


$(bin)/aaa.o:   $(src)/aaa.c $(src)/ddd.h
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(src)/aaa.c

$(bin)/bbb.o:   $(src)/bbb.c $(src)/aaa.h $(src)/bbb.h $(src)/ddd.h $(src)/fff.h
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(src)/bbb.c

$(bin)/ccc.o:   $(src)/ccc.c $(src)/aaa.h $(src)/fff.h
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(src)/ccc.c


# ... (and so on for all other .o files


clean:          
                rm $(bin)/*
```

---

### #includes in files

aaa.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "aaa.h"
#include "ddd.h"
```

bbb.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "aaa.h"
#include "bbb.h"
#include "ddd.h"
#include "fff.h"
```

ccc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

#include "aaa.h"
#include "fff.h"
```

---

when ran, It gave me this error:

```
"gcc" "-std=c11" -c src/lib/aaa.c
src/lib/aaa.c: In function ‘init_fileSize’:
src/lib/aaa.c:103:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  103 |     if((fd = fileno(arg->srcstream)) == -1)
      |              ^~~~~~
"gcc" "-std=c11" -c src/lib/bbb.c
"gcc" "-std=c11" -c src/lib/ccc.c
src/lib/ccc.c: In function ‘closeProgram’:
src/lib/ccc.c:10:15: error: ‘STDIN_FILENO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   10 |     tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &(trml->termios_default));
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib/ccc.c:10:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [makefile:19: bin/ccc.o] Error 1
```

---

from the error message, I conclude that the gcc couldn't find the definitions for functions and other identities declared in standard headers like stdio.h.

### How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of the *code* to show us.

Comment: Also note that the symbols `fileno` or `STDIN_FILENO` are not standard C symbols. They are specific to POSIX systems (like Unix, Linux and macOS). And `STDIN_FILENO` is not defined or declared in `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Simplest for you is to change `-std=c11` to `-std=gnu18` (since you should be using the latest standard).  Using `gnu` instead of `c` means that all sorts of extra declarations (such as those from POSIX) become visible.  Alternatively, compile with options such that `_XOPEN_SOURCE`  is defined as 700 before the first system header is included.  For example, a compile-line option `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`, or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` before the first line.  You can also play with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` but the numbers are harder to remember (you want `200809` ti match `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These preprocessor symbols and functions are not a part of Standard C. They are defined in the POSIX standard.

> On program startup, the integer file descriptors associated with
> the streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2,
> respectively.  **The preprocessor symbols STDIN_FILENO,
> STDOUT_FILENO, and STDERR_FILENO are defined with these values in
> <unistd.h>.**

So you're missing:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

for the macros.

And `fileno(3)` (declared in `stdio.h`),  requires a feature test macro to be defined:

```
/* Before including any headers, define this at the top. */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L

/* Now include the headers. */
```

Alternatively, you could replace `-std=cXX` with `-std=gnuXX`, and that will include all sorts of extensions to the language.

Comment: I just commented the value of CFLAGS variable in makefile and left its value blank, it resolved the "implicit declaration of fileno" warning, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> from the error message, I conclude that the gcc couldn't find the definitions for functions and other identities declared in standard headers like stdio.h.

Yes, but that's different from not being able to find `stdio.h` itself.  If it couldn't find the header then it would have also emitted a diagnostic about that.

The first issue is here:

> ```
> CFLAGS = "-std=c11"
> ```

That tells the compiler to use the syntax and semantics of C11, without enabling any syntactic or semantic extensions to that version of the C language.  It ***also*** tells the compiler to default to not enabling any *standard library* extensions.  Everything in the standard library that has to do with integer file handles falls in the latter category, including in particular the `fileno()` function and the `STDIN_FILENO` macro.

Additionally, `stdio.h` is not the documented location for for the `STDIN_FILENO` macro.  It is possible that you will still get that from `stdio.h` if the appropriate features are enabled, but the (POSIX) standard location for that macro is header `unistd.h`.  This entire header is an extension.

In source files that you want to compile with the `-std=c11` option and also want to access these library features, you need to define the appropriate feature-test macro(s), at the beginning, before any `#include` directives.  And you should include the headers documented to provide any particular features you need, rather than relying on obtaining them from an undocumented source.  For example,

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

// ...

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// ...
```

.